# How can I call an arbitrary interface method on a concrete instance in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interface, abstract-class

Lets say I have an interface with a couple abstract methods

```
class SomeInterface(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        """Does something i want all implementers to do"""

    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        """Does something i want all implementers to do"""
```

And a couple implementations

```
class A(SomeInterface):

    def foo(self):
        print("A does foo like this")

    def bar(self):
        print("A does bar like this")

class B(SomeInterface):

    def foo(self):
        print("B does foo like this")

    def bar(self):
        print("B does bar like this")
```

With that set up, I'm in a situation where i want to have a function that can run some interface function that i specify on some implementations of that interface. So, the function can take as parameters some form of reference to either foo or bar, and then run that on some instances of A and B that it creates. Something like this:

```
def run_any_interface_method(func: Callable):
    a = A()
    a.func()
    
    b = B()
    b.func()
    
run_any_interface_method(SomeInterface.foo)
```

But this wont work of course. What should be the best solution? I may have many possible implementations of SomeInterface and many interface functions. I considered this solution:

```
def run_any_interface_method(func: Callable):
    a = A()
    func(a)
    
    b = B()
    func(b)
    
run_any_interface_method(SomeInterface.foo)
```

Which passes the instance, either `A`or `B`, as the argument `self`, but `func` in this case is still the unimplemented abstractmethod, so it does nothing (interestingly, it does not complain when doing so). I considered iterating through the names of the methods to find the right one, but that seems kludgy. Is there a better way?

**Edit**
The solution i went with is:

```
from operator import methodcaller

def run_any_interface_method(func: Callable):
    func = methodcaller(func.__name__)
    a = A()
    func(a)

    b = B()
    func(b)

run_any_interface_method(SomeInterface.foo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `func` be an instance of `operator.methodcaller`.

```
from operator import methodcaller


def run_any_interface_method(func):
    a = A()
    func(a)

    b = B()
    func(b)

# Run a.foo() and b.foo()
run_any_interace_method(methodcaller('foo'))

# Run a.bar() and b.bar()
run_any_interace_method(methodcaller('bar'))
```

You can also take a string as an argument instead and construct the `methodcaller` instance inside the function.

```
def run_any_interface_method(method_name):
    func = methodcaller(method_name)
    a = A()
    func(a)

    b = B()
    func(b)

# Run a.foo() and b.foo()
run_any_interace_method('foo')

# Run a.bar() and b.bar()
run_any_interace_method('bar')
```

Comment: This seems quite good! I would like to have avoided using the string name of the method, but i suppose a single `.__name__` call isn't so bad.

Comment: I don't really see why you would need `__name__`. Just use `methodcaller('foo')` anywhere you would be using `SomeInterface.foo` in whatever chain leads to `run_any_interface_method` being called.

Comment: The main reason id prefer passing SomeInterface.foo is IDE integration. That way, if i misspell .foo pycharm in my case will warn me that it is an unresolved reference. "foo" has no such checking. The same is true for refactoring/renaming, pycharm will rename SomeInterface.foo for me. (Not that I _should_ ever be renaming interface methods :p)

Comment: But `SomeInterface.foo` simply isn't a reference to anything you want to use. Don't let your IDE dictate the code you write.

Comment: Hmm, im not sure, since `SomeInterface.foo` is an abstract method, using it as reference, at least to me, implies some or any child implementation. If i were writing hints in a comment for some instance `x` for example, and i did not know the type of `x`, I'd still say "must implement `SomeInterface.foo`". And the implication would be some specific implementation, since it is an abstracmethod, not simply taking `SomeInterface.foo` at face value.

Comment: Also, its not just IDEs. Any static checker will probably not work with a string reference. I agree that we shouldn't be influenced by IDEs but we can at least throw them a bone.